# How to load module not in INC in Perl during runtime?

Tags: perl, perl-module

How do I load a module with a path not in the @INC in Perl?

I've read the answers on how to add a path to the @INC, but the issue is that @INC has to be changed at the beginning of the code. After it's compiled, all the modules I've come across look to @INC to find the location of the module. My issue is that we're trying to separate out all these environment specific things to a config file. If it's in a config file, the path needs to be read before it can be pushed to @INC, but then the code has already been compiled and it seems @INC can't be modified.

1. Is there a way? Is there a library that lets me load a module and pass it a custom path?
2. Is this a terrible bad thing to do? Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perl has an incremental compilation model which means that code can be executed before other code is even parsed. For this, we can use *phase blocks* (aka. *phasers*):

```
BEGIN {
    print "This is executed as soon as the block has been parsed\n";
}
```

Such a phase block could also be used to load a configuration file.

For example, `use` statements are effectively syntactic sugar for a `BEGIN` block.

```
use Foo::Bar qw/baz qux/;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
    require Foo::Bar; # or: require "Foo/Bar.pm";
    Foo::Bar->import(qw/baz qux/);
}
```

We can also load modules at runtime, although that's only sensible for object-oriented modules.

So we have three options:

1. Load config in the `BEGIN` phase and add the correct library paths before loading the actual modules
2. Load the modules manually during `BEGIN` with their full path (e.g. `require "/my/modules/Foo/Bar.pm"`
3. Figure out the configuration at runtime, load modules after that.

Using bare `require` is fairly uncomfortable, which is why [`Module::Runtime`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime) exists

Comment: I went with 1, which solved the issue I posted about, but now I have a whole set of issues since I guess all the stuff in the begin is scoped to just that and I can't access it outside. So I have have to read the config again, but I can't access the same parameters using GetOptions.

Comment: @undefinedvariable You can declare variables outside of `BEGIN`, but assign them inside: `my $foo; BEGIN { $foo = "bar" } baz($foo);`

Comment: Ah, thank you. I thought BEGIN was executed before even declarations. Seems like I need to read that documentation again.

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`BEGIN`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/BEGIN.html) block to load your custom `@INC` location and then [`use lib`](http://perldoc.perl.org/lib.html) to include it.

```
# use lib /a special directory/
BEGIN {
    my $lib_to_include = ...;

    require lib;
    lib->import($lib_to_include);
}

use Module_That_Requires_Special_Dir;
```

The only thing to note is that whatever code you use to load your custom include directory will have to rely on methods already defined before this `BEGIN` block.   Therefore you can't use a subroutine that is later in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Came across [only](http://search.cpan.org/~ingy/only-0.28/lib/only.pm#LOADING_MULTIPLE_MODULE_VERSIONS_%28at_the_same_time%29), which seems to let a path be passed to the `use` argument like so:

```
use only { versionlib => '/home/ingy/modules' },
        MyModule => 0.33;
```

It has to be used with a version condition, but putting this here anyways since it's relevant to my question 1 and I wasn't able to find any modules first time around that allowed a path outside @INC.

[require](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/require.html) supposedly is able to take in a full path, according to the [perlfaq](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq8.html#What%27s-the-difference-between-require-and-use%3f) with

```
require "$ENV{HOME}/lib/Foo.pm"; # no @INC searching!
```